# Magento 2.4.2 - JS bundling not working

Tags: magento2, javascript, jsbundling

I have enabled the Javascript bundling, however, it doesn't seem to work properly.

I can see the bundles are being created in pub/static/vendor/theme/en_GB/js:

[image]

However, the bundles are not being loaded on the website:

[image]

I am in production mode. Disabled all 3rd party modules and themes. Still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Although Magento was saying the deploy mode is set to production, it was still locked at default at NginX. I had to add:

```
location / {
...
   fastcgi_param   MAGE_MODE  production; #MAGE_MODE = production
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did the following and the problem was solved:

> bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> bin/magento deploy:mode:set production -s

Here was the secret: run the di:compile after production

> bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy